# Задача на С++ (Напишите игру Rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock.)

Tags: c++

Здрасте,я написал игру,но теперь, нужно ее модернизировать, я так и не понял что от меня хотят, надеюсь поможете вот:

2. Реализуйте программу таким образом, чтобы пользователь мог повторить игру столько раз, сколько захочет.
   Выведите сообщение типа Try again? и варианты ответа:
   Yes ([y]) и No ([n]).
3. По завершению игры выведите статистику по игре. Количество побед user, computet и сколько раз сыграли в ничью.

Я так и непонял что от меня хотят. Ответьте мне пожалуйста или скиньте  код с этим модификациями.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int number;
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> number;
int count = 0;

while (number>0 || number < 0) {
    number /= 10;
    count++;
}
cout << count << endl;*/
char exit;
int count = 0;
while (true)
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    count++;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Try again? [y] - yes; [n] - no: ";
        cin >> exit;
        if (exit == 'y' || exit == 'n')break;
        else cout << "Select true option!" << endl;
    }
    if (exit == 'n')break;
}
cout << count << endl;

int number;
while (true) {
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;

    if (number == 0)break;
    if (number % 3 == 0 || number % 7 == 0)continue;
    cout << number << endl;
}

int answer;
do {
    cout << "2 + 2 = ?:";
    cin >> answer;
} while (answer != 4);
char again = ' ';
do {
    int number = 100 / 2;
    int step = 100 / 2;
    char answer;
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        count++;
        cout << "Number is [>][<][=] " << number << ": ";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == '>') {
            step /= 2;
            if (step == 0) step = 1;
            number += step;
        }
        else if (answer == '<') {
            step /= 2;
            if (step == 0) step = 1;
            number -= step;
        }
        else if (answer == '=') {
            cout << "Your magic number " << number << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (count == 10) { cout << "Error!!!" << endl; break; }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Try again [y] - yes; [n] - no: ";
        cin >> again;
        if (again == 'y' || again == 'n')break;
        else cout << "Select true option!" << endl;
    }
    
} while (again != 'n');


int number = 123456; // 345612
int ofsset = 2;
int new_number = 0;
int start, end; // start = 3456; end = 12
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> number;
cout << "Set ofsset: ";
cin >> ofsset;
int count = 0,n=1, flag = number;

while (number > 0) {
number /= 10;
count++;
}
number = flag;
for (int i = 0; i < count - ofsset; i++) {
n *= 10;
}
start = number % n; // 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 
end = number / n;
n = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < ofsset; i++) {
n *= 10;
}
cout << n << endl;
new_number = start * n + end;

3456 * 100 + 12// 10 * 10
new_number = start * 100 + end;
cout << number << " => " << new_number << endl;
srand(time(0));

cout << "Rock, scissors, paper" << endl;
cout << "Start Game" << endl;

int user_point = 0, comp_point = 0;
char user_select = ' ', comp_select = ' ';

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    cout << "Round " << i << endl;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Select choice:\n\t\t[r] - rock;\n\t\t[s] - scissors;\n\t\t[p] - paper;\n\tInput: ";
        cin >> user_select;
        if (user_select == 'r' || user_select == 's' || user_select == 'p')break;
        else cout << "Select true option!" << endl;
    }
    switch (1 + rand() % 3)
    {
    case 1: comp_select = 'r'; break;
    case 2: comp_select = 's'; break;
    case 3: comp_select = 'p'; break;
    }
    cout << "Computer select: " << comp_select << endl;
    if (user_select == comp_select) {
        cout << "Draw!!" << endl;
    }
    else if (user_select == 'r' && comp_select == 's') {
        user_point++;
        cout << "User win" << endl;
    }
    else if (user_select == 's' && comp_select == 'p') {
        user_point++;
        cout << "User win" << endl;
    }
    else if (user_select == 'p' && comp_select == 'r') {
        user_point++;
        cout << "User win" << endl;
    }
    else {
        comp_point++;
        cout << "Computer wins!" << endl;
    }
}

if (user_point == comp_point) {
    cout << "Draw" << endl;
}
else if (user_point > comp_point) {
    cout << "Congratulation!!!! User win!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Sorry ...... Computer wins" << endl;
}
int min = 5;
int max = 10;
cout << min + rand() % (max - min + 1) << endl;
cout << rand() << endl;

}
```

Comment: Вам непонятен смысл п. 2 и 3? Или в чем затруднения?

Comment: Я так понимаю, тот код который вы выложили содержит не только код с которым нужна помощь. Если я правильно понимаю, то пожалуйста уберите ненужный код, чтобы мы быстрей могли вам помочь.

Comment: Я изложил сюда код с игрой,но нужно в этот код с игрой ище кинуть модификации которые я упомянул п. 2 и 3,тоесть мне нужен этот код,но с модификациями,тоесть фундамент я уже вам скинул,ну нужно на него ище накинуть эту статистику и тп

Comment: Я понимаю, но излишке кода лишь мешают понимаю.  Например зачем нам код игры с магическим числом?

Answer (score 1):

Например вы можете сделать так:

```
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int playerWins = 0, draw = 0, computerWins = 0;
char next = 'y';

cout << "Rock, scissors, paper" << endl;
cout << "Start Game" << endl;

while (next == 'y') {

    cout << "Ваша игра!" << endl;

    game_func(playerWins, draw, computerWins);

    do {
        cout << "Продолжить? (y/n): ";
        cin >> next;
    } while (next != 'y' && next != 'n');
}

cout << "Результаты: " << endl;
cout << "Вы победили " << playerWins << " раз." << endl;
cout << "Компьютер победил " << computerWins << " раз." << endl;
cout << "Ничьих " << draw << " раз." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Желательно логику игры вынести в отдельную функцию, чтобы не нагромождать `main`.

В коде выше, мы по ссылке передаем в функцию игры 3 переменные, которые увеличиваются в зависимости от результата игры. И в конце когда пользователь введет `n` мы выводим результаты на экран.

Сама функция `game_func` почти не отличается от вашего кода, только добавлено увеличение переменных, которые отвечают за результат игры в конце:

```
void game_func(int& playerWins, int& draw, int& computerWins) {
int user_point = 0, comp_point = 0;
char user_select = ' ', comp_select = ' ';

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    cout << "Round " << i << endl;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Select choice:\n\t\t[r] - rock;\n\t\t[s] - scissors;\n\t\t[p] - paper;\n\tInput: ";
        cin >> user_select;
        if (user_select == 'r' || user_select == 's' || user_select == 'p')break;
        else cout << "Select true option!" << endl;
    }
    switch (1 + rand() % 3)
    {
    case 1: comp_select = 'r'; break;
    case 2: comp_select = 's'; break;
    case 3: comp_select = 'p'; break;
    }
    cout << "Computer select: " << comp_select << endl;
    if (user_select == comp_select) {
        cout << "Draw!!" << endl;
    }
    else if (user_select == 'r' && comp_select == 's') {
        user_point++;
        cout << "User win" << endl;
    }
    else if (user_select == 's' && comp_select == 'p') {
        user_point++;
        cout << "User win" << endl;
    }
    else if (user_select == 'p' && comp_select == 'r') {
        user_point++;
        cout << "User win" << endl;
    }
    else {
        comp_point++;
        cout << "Computer wins!" << endl;
    }
}

if (user_point == comp_point) {
    //Увеличиваем счетчик ничьих
    ++draw;
    cout << "Draw" << endl;
}
else if (user_point > comp_point) {
    //Увеличиваем счетчик побед игрока
    ++playerWins;
    cout << "Congratulation!!!! User win!" << endl;
}
else {
    //И так же компьютера.
    ++computerWins;
    cout << "Sorry ...... Computer wins" << endl;
}
}
```

Так же вместе ссылок можно использовать глобальные переменные. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо,только у меня впорос: Это сразу с игрой вы мне кинули? Тоесть это игра + модификации?

Comment: @Stasonom функция `game_func` содержит в себе полностью ваш код игры + дополнение (вы их можете найти там где комментарии). Если я вам помог, то лучшая благодарность будет если вы выберите мой ответ как "Правильный ответ" :)

Comment: Понял,спасибо,только здесь вроде вы не добавили Ящерецу и Спока

Comment: @Stasonom хмм в вопросе написано только про п.2 и п.3.

Comment: @Stasonom Попробуйте сами дополнить свою игру. Просто проверки например: `if(игрок == камень && (компьютер или ножницы или ящерицу))` тогда игрок победил